# Send HTTP Post When Google Spreadsheet Updated

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets

I already have a spreadsheet that submitted by 3rd party apps (which I can't change its code).

Then, I need to send HTTP (Post) automatically to http://THISISMYURL.url/go.aspx?fieldone=xxx&fieldtwo=xxx when my Google spreadsheet updated.

What in my mind is to create a script in Google Spreadsheet and use UrlFetchApp in my code.

```
function SendHTTPpost() {

//How to pick data from any field in last column (everytime google spreadsheet updated)?

  var data =
   {
    "fieldOne" : "value for field one (from last column)",
    "fieldTwo" : "value for field two (from last column)",
   };
   var options =
   {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : data
   };
 UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://THISISMYURL.url/go.aspx", options);
 }
```

I know that I missed some command which to fetch some data from spreadsheet. Anybody get some idea to do this?

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: There are lots of examples showing how to read data from a spreadsheet, and it is included in Google's tutorials. There are many ways this can be accomplished, depending on your particular requirements and preferences - more than can be reasonably answered here. In my opinion, this question is too broad for this forum.

Comment: @Mogsdad, thanks for the clue that you leave it here "read data from a spreadsheet". I'll let you know my updates here.

Comment: I found this:
`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();`
Will go through this code to solve my puzzle. :)

Comment: What have you tried regarding reading the spreadsheet? look at spreadsheetApp documentation and update yoir code using that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mogsdad for giving a clue for me. And thanks to @Zig Mandel for suggesting me to read spreadsheetApp documentation.

Here are what I did in my code, and it's works!

```
// get the spreadsheet object
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
// set the first sheet as active
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
// fetch this sheet
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

// figure out what the last row is
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
```

At the last command, I use UrlFetchApp classes by fetch(url) method that I learn from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String))

Thanks to all for helping me.
And hopefully it will help others too.
Yeay!!!